# Is it possible to merge these 2 SPF records?

Tags: spf

I'm attempting to set up mailerlite with authentication and they provided me with this SPF record to add to my domain.

I added the record but now I have 2 and the authenticator says that I can only have 1 SPF record and that I need to merge the 2 records into 1 for both to work.

Is it possible to merge these 2 SPF records into 1 spf record?

cPanel SPF record:

```
v=spf1 ip4:162.0.229.20 ip4:162.0.229.21 include:spf.web-hosting.com +a +mx +ip4:198.54.114.47 +ip4:198.54.114.173 ~all
```

Mailerlite SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.mlsend.com ip4:162.0.229.20 ip4:162.0.229.21 include:spf.web-hosting.com +a +mx +ip4:198.54.114.47 +ip4:198.54.114.173 ~all
```

Comment: The second one is already an extension of the first, it contains everything the first one contains plus a new entry for Mailerlite, so just use the second one!

Comment: Also, it's the wrong place here for this question, because Stack Overflow is about programming questions, not DNS administration. That would be better posted on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, these are essentially the same, but you can optimise them a little.

- Put literal `ip4` and `ip6` mechanisms first as they can be resolved without DNS lookups
- You don't need to use `+` prefixes because that's the default action
- Put `a` before `mx` as it likely involves fewer lookups
- Put `include`s last for the same reason

Resulting in:

```
v=spf1 ip4:198.54.114.47 ip4:198.54.114.173 ip4:162.0.229.20 ip4:162.0.229.21 a mx include:_spf.mlsend.com include:spf.web-hosting.com ~all
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one seems to include every info that's present in the first one, so why not just use it and not add the second one?